# How to delete spacing after row is complete in c++?

Tags: c++

I have been working on a project. I am limited to using a few libraries so any additional library would not be helpful. So far my project works, but I am noticing an extra space after the last row is completed. How do I fix this extra spacing issue? please help! There's a space at the bottom... and this only seems to happen when the last row is full and no date is carried over.

```
// Extracted.. 
#include <iostream>

         if (day >= 9)
         {
            std::cout << day;
         }
         else
         {
          std::cout << day << " ";
         }
         if (day != days_per)
         {
          std::cout << " ";
         }
         }
```

Comment: Here's how to do it: simply use your debugger to run your program, one line at a time, step by step, and pay attention to the exact sequence of events that produces the extra line of output. Once you understand the logical flaw that produces this result it should be clear what change needs to be made to fix it. Have you tried, yet, to run your program in the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: Yep! I have tried. I think I know where the fixing goes, but I can not figure out how to implement it or write it..

Comment: Why don't you add the details of what you found, and ask about ***that***, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will fix it:

- That's the block dealing with the last day of the week (Saturday).
- Print it always.
- If it is the last day of the month, don't do anything else.
- Otherwise: 1) print a newline, and 2) if the next day has 1 digit (current `day < 9`), print a space.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/53zd3K5h4)

```cpp
      if (++count > 6)
      {
         count = 0;
         std::cout << day;
         if (day != days_per)
         {
            std::cout << '\n';
            if (day < 9)
            {
                std::cout << " ";
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to delete anything, just dont produce it. Your probelm is here

```
         if (day >= 9)
        {
            std::cout << day << '\n';
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << day << '\n' << " ";
        }
```

when you come to the end of a line you do a line feed if even it was the last day.

change to

```
     if (day >= 9)
     {
        std::cout << day;
        if (day != days_per) std::cout << '\n';
     }
     else
     {
        std::cout << day << '\n' << " ";
     }
```

you dont need it on the other path because thats never hit at the end of the month (day is alwasy 2 digits)

Comment: `std::cout << day << ((days != days_per) ? "\n" : "");` and the change is even shorter :)

Comment: @rturrado shorted does not always mean more clear

Comment: @rturrado i started with that but it was not clear

Comment: @JohnFilleau, that's right. pm100, I appreciated you tried to change the least from the original code to make it more understandable.